# Navigation won't show in IE9

Tags: jquery, navigation, internet-explorer-9

My navigation won't show in IE9, but it will in every other browser.

Please help, not sure about IE8, or before..

What is my problem?
Website: www.govansk.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is moving jQuery up to be the first included JavaScript file. That solves the "jQuery is undefined" error. Move it before `cufon-yui.js`:

```
<!-- ////////////////////////////////// -->
<!-- //      Javascript Files        // -->
<!-- ////////////////////////////////// -->
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></SCRIPT>
```

<del>And then you seem to be missing the include for the s3slider plugin. Judging by a quick Google search, you must have this line somewhere after including jQuery:</del>

```
<script src="js/s3Slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Of course, you must ensure the presence of that file. Maybe that offending line is a leftover from before switching to whatever nivo slider is, because both seem to be targeting the `#slider` element.

I'm pretty sure that's it. Remove this code:

```
$("#slider").s3Slider({
    timeOut: 12000,
    captionOpacity: 0.7            
});
```

EDIT: As for Cufon, I found this post:
http://blog.ninanet.com/2011/04/29/cufon-and-ie9

If it doesn't help, I suggest more Googling about Cufon in IE. I have no experience with Cufon, so I can't help you further, I'm afraid.

Comment: This removes all errors, but my navigation as well as titles do not work?

Comment: Well that's weird, it works if I open it locally - I saved the complete page to disk.

Comment: Are you using IE9? I think it has something to do with CUFON. IE9 doesn't load any of the cufon text.

Comment: Aye, it replaces the text with some sort of squiggly handwriting-like text locally in IE9. It doesn't do that in neither Chrome nor Firefox online, but at least the navigation is visible there with normal text.

Comment: Not with IE9 it doesn't replace the text? It's just nothing? Please see; http://i46.tinypic.com/2vuecso.png

Comment: Thank you everything is working again, much appreciated!!!

Comment: You're welcome. And for the sake of completeness, here's the thing apparently working locally in IE9: http://i50.tinypic.com/10wmauw.jpg *IF* that's how it was supposed to look.

Comment: It was actually supposed to have a background, but I'm guessing this isn't showing up since your picture is local?